# Application Not Installed, packages are different

Tags: java, android, apk

I have created an app, that actualy another app, just changed a little bit by me. When I trying to install it system thinks, that this is the same app, and i get an error "Application Not Installed. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed" The package have a different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the application package name in AndroidManifest.xml , system read package name from there.

it will be in `manifest` tag like `package="com.xxx.xxx"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
```